# Jhipster gradle jpa meta model generation

Tags: jpa, build.gradle, jhipster

Does anyone know how to modify the default configuration of `build.gradle` of a jhipster project to allow gradle to generate `jpa` meta model classes?

By default it seems that it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me using JHipster 4.7.0, I have an entity named `Country` and the static meta model is generated  under `build/generated/source/apt/main/com/example/domain/Country_.java` when I run gradlew

Comment: Did you do something particular for generate it?  I mean any gradle task, "yo jhipster " or something similar?

Comment: I just added JPA filtering option to my existing entity while re-generating it with `jhipster entity Country`. I compared the build.gradle file and gradle folder before and after nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do something particular to generate it?

I mean something like "gradlew", "yo jhipster"..

Thanks